# How to know/expand my limits?

Tags: feature-request, support, limits

How do I know how many questions I can ask per day or per month? How do I increase these limits?

I mean, at the moment, how do I know, how many more questions I can ask?

And, suppose I reached some limit -- then how do I know when it will be removed?